# -[20.04, 2008 White Unibody Macbook] Battery charges to 55%, then declares it is full until it is unplugged showing it at 55%

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, macbook

The battery on my laptop is basically brand new, we bought it new from a non-apple brand around a year ago. The laptop charges properly, however, when it reaches 55% it believes it's full and quits charging, only showing that it's full. It charged to 100% perfectly fine on macOS Lion, but only now has the issue arisen.

Does this seem to be a battery or OS issue? Is it fixable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [said](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/gos4xl/battery_charges_to_55_but_then_says_its_full/fridnxk/) by u/michaelMATE on Reddit:

> I have this “issue” on my Macbook Pro as well, the truth is Linux is more honest about your actual capacity, while Mac OS gives you the percentage based on the the remaining capacity. If you download Coconut Battery on Mac you’ll see what I mean. Sorry mate, you probably just have a really old battery and Linux is just honest with you :D

Coconut Battery gave a 55% battery life. It seems he was 100% correct here.